# Google Analytics not working in 1.7.0.2 (community edition)

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, google-analytics

currently in that version of magento community, have done the "enable" button and entered account, no dice. Read on forum about a fix, not working. Im not getting ANY evidence to appear in my page source. I am not a proficcient in these languages, please be as elementary in ur response as possible, it wont hurt my feelings lol :) Heres the code for the 2 relevant (i think) files:
**googleanalytics.xml**

```
<layout version=\"0.1.0\">

<!--
Default layout, loads most of the pages
-->

<default>
    <!-- Mage_GoogleAnalytics -->
    <reference name="before_body_end">
        <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" template="googleanalytics/ga.phtml" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

`ga.phtml`

```
<?php

?>
<?php if (!Mage::helper('core/cookie')->isUserNotAllowSaveCookie()): ?>
<?php $accountId = Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_GoogleAnalytics_Helper_Data::XML_PATH_ACCOUNT) ?>
<!-- BEGIN GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODEs -->
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    <?php echo $this->_getPageTrackingCode($accountId) ?>
    <?php echo $this->_getOrdersTrackingCode() ?>

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();

//]]>
</script>
<!-- END GOOGLE ANALYTICS CODE -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another potential way you could do it, is if you have the analytics code like you would put in any other website, head over to:

**head.phtml** of your theme file and drop the analytics code in there, or
Go into your admin back end under design, and enter the code under 'miscellaneous code'.

Depending how you want to structure it their is multiple ways :)

Comment: Thanks Adam. New to magento, racked my brains over this issue. Preciate it!

Comment: No problem Jimmy, remember with magento there are multiple ways to do everything, I find the Admin->design-> miscellaneous code way useful if you do multiple store views so you can analyse each website, but also header.phtml if you want a quick fix.There is lots of ways to do one thing. Also, welcome to the magento community, its a steep learning curve but fun!

Comment: @Jimmy I would suggest you add google tag manager instead and install everything through there. Its easier when it comes time to update, etc..

Answer (score 0):

GA won't work if you have the new EU law cookie restriction enabled and you haven't accepted the cookie storage yet on frontend.
If the value of the setting in `System->Configuration->Web->Session Cookie Management->Cookie Restriction Mode` is set to `Yes`, then you need to set it to `No` or, on frontend, allow the website to set cookies.
**[EDIT]**
An other think that I experienced regarding GA, not sure if it's your case, but it might help others. I was having a similar issue after an upgrade from EE 1.11 to 1.12 (similar to CE 1.6 to 1.7). The theme for the website was made on 1.11 by copying all the files in a new folder and modifying what was needed.
Here comes the issue. In 1.11 (ce 1.6) the GA layout file looks like this:

```
<default>
    <!-- Mage_GoogleAnalytics -->
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="googleanalytics/ga" name="google_analytics" as="google_analytics" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

There was no template on the GA block because the code was rendered directly in the block. Since this change in EE 1.12 (CE 1.7) it stopped working.
You can check and make sure this is not the case for your theme.
Also, for every one that gets here...this is why you shouldn't create themes by cloning the base theme.

Comment: Thank you for your help Marius. Cookie Restriction Mode is currently set to no. By allow the website to set cookies, you mean each individual's browser settings?

Comment: No...I didn't mean that. I wanted to say that if the option was set to `Yes` you should click `Allow` on frontend. But that's not the case for you since cookie restriction mode is set to `No`.

Comment: It seems like this file is never getting called. Would it hurt to further define the location of this file in the GA block?  /public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the core (**base**) template file. I had a similar kind of problem. In my case, the problem was with google analytics layout file (**googleanalytics.xml**) present in my **custom theme folder**.

If you have a custom theme then the base templates and layouts are overridden by the template and layout files that are present in your custom theme folder.

Therefore,

Files under `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/` is overridden by files from `app/design/frontend/CUSTOM_PACKAGE/CUSTOM_THEME/template/` folder.

Similarly, files under `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/` is overridden by files from `app/design/frontend/CUSTOM_PACKAGE/CUSTOM_THEME/template/` folder.

If you have custom theme used in your webshop then checking if the following files are present inside custom theme and seeing their code might be helpful:-

> - app/design/frontend/CUSTOM_PACKAGE/CUSTOM_THEME/template/googleanalytics/ga.phtml
> - app/design/frontend/CUSTOM_PACKAGE/CUSTOM_THEME/layout/googleanalytics.xml